# How to create missing launch icon

Tags: icons, desktop-environments

I've installed the Arduino IDE but something must have not worked.  When I click the 9-dots at the bottom left of my screen to see all applications, the icon isn't there.  But if I use the file manager and double click on a .ino file, the IDE launches.

After searching here, I did ensure that there is a .desktop file in ~/local/share/applications and that the paths are correct.

What am I missing?

(This is 19.10 Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, I've done that.  There is a .desktop file both in ~/local/share/applications and in /usr/share/applications.  The path's are correct for both the executable and the icon.  The icon does not appear when I click the 9-dots on the bottom left of the screen.  (What is that called?)

Comment: Its called the hamburger menu...

Comment: Hamburger menu?  I'll bite, why?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hamburger-menu.htm

Comment: Well how about that?!?  Now I know what it is, if only I could get it working.

Comment: The path should be `~/.local/share/applications` I think you are missing `dot` in `.local`

Comment: Yes, typo in the post, it is .local